# How do I update dictionary from items of list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following problem:

Imagining that I killed a dragon and it drops loot, how do I update my inventory from the loot? I figured how to append if the loot does not exist in the inventory but if they already there, I am not sure how to update it.

Here are the codes:

```
UserInventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch':6, 'gold coin':42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def showstuff(storeno):
items_total = 0
for k, v in storeno.items():
    print('Item :' + k + '---' + str(v))
    items_total = items_total + v
print('Total Items:' + str(items_total))

'''def addstuff(inventory, additem):
    I'm not sure what to do here

dragonloot = ['gold coin', 'gold coin', 'rope']
addstuff(UserInventory, dragonloot)'''
showstuff(UserInventory)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at [Counters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch':6, 'gold coin':42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
inventory_ctr = Counter(inventory)

update = ['rope', 'torch']
update_ctr = Counter(update)

new_inventory_ctr = inventory_ctr + update_ctr

print(new_inventory_ctr)
```

Comment: No need to create 3 Counters. `inventory_ctr.update(['rope', 'torch'])` would do.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i know a new python module!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following sample code ...

```
def addstuff(inventory, additem):
    for newitem in additem:
        if newitem in inventory:
            inventory[newitem] += 1
        else:
            inventory[newitem] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This sample code is what exactly I want !!